# custom event listener - p5.js SceneManager

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to use scene manager in my p5.js application. However, this event is no longer working when I added it to the "gamescene".
These lines are on a global level:

```
function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  manager = new SceneManager();
  // Preload scenes. Preloading is normally optional
  // ... but needed if showNextScene() is used.
  manager.addScene ( startscene );
  manager.addScene ( gamescene );
  manager.showNextScene();
}
function onPointerlockChange(){
manager.handleEvent("onPointerlockChange");
}
document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', onPointerlockChange, false);
```

This is how I added the function to the gamescene:

```
function gamescene()
{
this.onPointerlockChange = function() {
    if (document.pointerLockElement === canvas.elt ||
      document.mozPointerLockElement === canvas.elt)
      console.log("locked");
    else {
      console.log("unlocked");
      player.pointerLock = false;
    }
    console.log("triggered");
  }
}
```

Could you please help me out with that? Thank you.

Comment: Please share a complete [mcve]. It's not clear that `this.onPointerlockChange` is ever invoked. What does ["not working"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) mean exactly? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I believe it is clear now

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: It's still not clear: `this.onPointerlockChange` was defined but never called anywhere. Please share complete code and a technical question about that code. Preferably, create a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Thanks.